# MS Access 2013: using MS Word's grammar check via VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, spell-checking

(solution below the question)

I have an access form which allows users to enter text in a text box (MYFIELD). I have the spell check option already set up automatically when the user exits the field

```
Private Sub MYFIELD_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strSpell
    strSpell = MYFIELD
    If IsNull(Len(strSpell)) Or Len(strSpell) = 0 Then
       Exit Sub
    End If
    With MYFIELD
        .SetFocus
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = Len(strSpell)
    End With
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

I want to enable also the grammar check. As it's not build in Access, I need to use word's one but I can't figure out how to do it.

I found this code on a [forum](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_22945101.html)

1) The guy who posted this says that his users "enter text into a large control. This control is then merged into a word document". My field is just a long text field, so can I still use (or adapt) the code below?

2)  If yes, I am not sure how to mix it with my code (despite all my search -I am not familiar with VBA-, I don't understand how calling this Public Function from my form):

```
Public Function SpellIt(ctl As Control)
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document


    On Error GoTo SpellIt_Err

   Set wdApp = New Word.Application

      If Not IsNull(ctl) Then
         Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
         wdApp.Selection.Text = ctl
         wdApp.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
         If Len(wdApp.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
            ctl = wdApp.Selection.Text
         Else
            wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            wdApp.Quit
            Set wdApp = Nothing
            Exit Function
         End If
         wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
      End If

   wdApp.Quit
   Set wdApp = Nothing

   MsgBox "Spelling and Grammar Check Complete.", vbInformation, "Microsoft Word Spelling And Grammar:"
   Exit Function

SpellIt_Err:
    Err.Clear
    ctl.Undo
    MsgBox "We encountered an error in it's conversation with Microsoft Word regarding your comment." & vbCrLf & _
        "As a precaution, any changes made within the grammar and spelling dialog box have not been retained.", _
        vbCritical, "Spelling and Grammar Check NOT Complete:"
End Function
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

HERE is the solution: (I needed to change ctl into ctrl)

```
Private Sub Description_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Call SpellIt(Description)
End Sub
Public Function SpellIt(ctrl As Control)
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document


    On Error GoTo SpellIt_Err

   Set wdApp = New Word.Application

      If Not IsNull(ctrl) Then
         Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
         wdApp.Selection.Text = ctrl
         wdApp.Dialogs(wdDialogToolsSpellingAndGrammar).Show
         If Len(wdApp.Selection.Text) <> 1 Then
            ctl = wdApp.Selection.Text
         Else
            wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            wdApp.Quit
            Set wdApp = Nothing
            Exit Function
         End If
         wdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
      End If

   wdApp.Quit
   Set wdApp = Nothing

   MsgBox "Spelling and Grammar Check Complete.", vbInformation, "Microsoft Word Spelling And Grammar:"
   Exit Function

SpellIt_Err:
    Err.Clear
    ctl.Undo
    MsgBox "We encountered an error in it's conversation with Microsoft Word regarding your comment." & vbCrLf & _
        "As a precaution, any changes made within the grammar and spelling dialog box have not been retained.", _
        vbCritical, "Spelling and Grammar Check NOT Complete:"
End Function
```

Comment: Just point the function towards the control object with the text in it. It will open word, run the Spelling/Grammar dialog box on the contents (`wdApp.Dialogs`) and then closes when done.

Comment: CheckGrammar method as it applies to the Application object.

Checks a string for grammatical errors. Returns a Boolean to indicate whether the string contains grammatical errors. True if the string contains no errors.

expression.CheckGrammar(String)

expression   Required. An expression that returns an Application object.

String  Required String. The string you want to check for grammatical errors.

Comment: Thanks phd!You give me somes clues to understand this piece of obscure code

Comment: Thank you @bmgh1985 for your help! I have updated the code above with my try for "pointing the function toward the control object with the text in it". But I am getting an error from Access : "procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name". Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? As you can see I'm a newbie, it may be obvious but I can't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @bmgh1985 I have done some more diggings but I am still stuck. I don't get how the grammar check is going to be launch (I am try to get it launch when I exit the field MYFIELD the one I want to be check by the grammar checker). Any advice will be very much appreciated ! Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your original post (probably add as an addendum to the bottom) to show what step you are at and what you are actually using as your code currently, as both the first and second bit are declared differently yet have the same name. Are you using either of them / both of them? It looks like that second code should work like a charm so your actual procedure should then just call the function and thats it, so I cant see where the problem is arising from here. As it stands, I am pretty much clueless as to where you are with it.

Comment: @bmgh1985. Thanks for your help! I have edited my post so you can understand the step I have gone through. I think my big problem is that I am clueless about how the function will be launched. How should I tell the function to start when a particular event happen? (I did it the same it's done with `Private Sub : MYFIELD_Exit`  but it's seems that is not working).

Comment: OK. You seem to be getting a bit mixed up. Will stick up an answer addressing the issues

Comment: Thanks a lot... actually I am not surprised, all those codes are very foggy to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you seem to be getting confused with what a function actually is. A function is of the form `Function(Arguments)` and is called from within a Sub. It does not run as a standalone and should not be treated as such. An example of this that is already available is `MsgBox()`. You call the `MsgBox` function, which takes an argument (or arguments in this case) and puts that through the function, translating that into what you need.

First things first. The Textbox you have is called MYFIELD. That is your Control. Best not to have the Function have the same name. Rename this to something like `Public Function ButChng(ctrl as Control)`. The function itself does not need to be touched from how it was originally.

In your `MYFIELD_Exit` sub, all you then need to do is call the function. So it will read like this:

```
Private Sub MYFIELD_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Call ButChng(MYFIELD) 'this puts the MYFIELD control as your variable to go through ButChng
Exit Sub
```

It should then work as intended.

Comment: Ok, I have deleted everything in VBA, and I have changed the `MYFIELD` name to `Description` then I have enter the code under `Option Compare Database`. I also kept the original function with SpellIt so I am sure I am not messing this code up. I have try my best to do what you say (I am not sure if I should delete the 2 words `Public Function` though)but Access still give me an error: Sub or Function not defined and highligth Description in `SpellIt (Description)`. Please have a look at the update in my question (at the bottom) for the code I made up. Any idea why? Sorry for being so silly..

Comment: You seem to be missing a couple of lines. After `SpellIt (Description)`, you need to add `End Sub` and after that you need to declare the function with the line `Public Function SpellIt(ctrl as Control)` as once again you seem to be mixing your Functions and Subs. Heres some links to help explain it in more detail for you: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/function-sub.html and http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx (that last site I cannot recommend highly enough for learning the ins and outs of VBA)

Comment: oh, just seen the Exit Sub there at the very bottom. Get rid of that too

Comment: OK It did it, but I am still getting an error: run time error 424 object required. (see the highlighted line http://tinypic.com/r/j7gbir/8). Does this have to do with the fact that I have a class file instead of a basic file? (in the links you gave me, they say to use "module"). Module1 is empty, all my codes are in Form_Movie_Form.  I am very grateful for your patience!

Comment: Also, I have updated the code in my question to match what you ask me to do in your last comment.

Comment: Ok thank to you it's solved. The spelling checker, there is still some issues, but I will post another question for that. I need to add call before `SpellIt (Description)`. Also I change the `ctl` into `ctrl` as in `Public Function SpellIt(ctrl as Control)` (as in your comment but not as in the original code) and the rest of the code. Thanks a lot for your time and your help, and also your patience!

Comment: Ah good. Call isnt necessary but its good practice to have it in there. If doing it without, it would work writing it as `Spellit Description` (but thats my error :P) Will amend OP

Comment: Thanks, I will remember that the next time!